# Copy and paste between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

This is a question and may or may not be achievable but any recommendation is much appreciated.

Is it possible to have one workbook (wrkbookA) open that has all the data and vba code in it. Click button to open/navigate to a directory and select another workbook (wrkbookB). wrkbookB is opened, select a column, that column is copied and pasted into wrkbookA in column A and wrkbookB is closed.

I know this can be achieved using a constant column from wrkbookB but the data is in differnet columns in each workbook in wrkbookB.

I have also looked at column headings and doing the copy that way but it is not an option as there are different columns with similar heading/words.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: If you can't determine which column the data should go in, then you're going to have to ask the user, maybe using an [inputbox](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/inputbox.htm)?

Comment: Stuart, The column that needs to be copied is not known, even if i do use ask the user, what would the code look like? Thanks.

Comment: I recommend taking a step back and see if you can standardize wrkbookB first.  Why would the data be in different locations every time?  If someone is entering data by hand, you can just give them a heavily protected Excel template.

Comment: That is the problem. The data is within these workbooks and each workbook comes from different companies. I cant ask the companies to standardise their workflow for me :) Is what described above possible? If not any suggestions please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have any way of knowing which Column will need to be selected from workbook B, you're going to need user interaction. that being the case, why not write a sub that will do the following:

1. Have user select workbook B to open
2. Place a button in Workbook B attached to code in Workbook A

User then, in Workbook B, selects the column they want copied and push the button which copies that column to Workbook A and closes Workbook B without saving changes.

### Sample Code Idea:

```
Workbooks.Open ...
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(427.5, 12.75, 104.25, 36).OnAction = "WorkBookA!MoveColumn"
```

Comment: I did think of that but wrkbook B is sent to me from other companies and is not an internal application. So putting the button in each sheet is not the way. Unless there is a way of implementing/pushing the code+button to wrkbook B when it is opened by wrkbook A???

Comment: No... Have the macro from workbook A actually PUT the button in workbook B as it opens it and assign it the correct `move` sub from workbook A - (so everything is controlled via workbook A), then close it without saving changes

Comment: Yes that sounds perfect...but how do you go about doing that? How can I push the button from wrkbook A to wrkbook B? Do you have an example code please? Thanks.

Comment: Updated the solution with VERY simplistic sample code to add a button to a workbook and assign it a macro

Comment: If all other columns in workbookB received from clients empty, you can run a macro from workbookA which looks for the filled column, once found, copy across to wrkbookA (or process directly without copying). This would avoid having to  manually select the column...Or if the column in workbookB has a specific text you can look for to identify, that will also work....

Comment: Thanks John for the code, it did indeed help alot. Is there a way ofpushing action code for that button so when clicked it could copy range selected to Workbook A?

Comment: ... I don't understand your question - If you wrote into your `WorkBookA!MoveColumn` sub code to copy the selected column from the currently active workbook back to workbook A, that would do what you want, no??